# How to change list item color with JQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I have a menu that when certain items (li classes) are clicked, it scrolls to the appropriate point. I was wondering how I could keep that same list item in a certain state while it is scrolled at the appropriate point, and change it back accordingly, depending on what list item is clicked? Any help would be great.

Here is my JQuery --->

```
<script>
$(function() {  
$('.full-web').click(function(){
    $(this).css('backgroundColor', '#e9f7ff');
    $(this).css('color', '#000828');
    $(this).css('borderBottomColor', '#000828');
    $(this).css('borderBottomWidth', '10px')

  });
});
</script>
```

HTML --->

```
<nav class="container">
<ul>
<li class="full-web" style="background-color:#3a9bc3;">FULL WEBSITES</li>
<li class="ui" style="background-color:#50a2c3;">UI/DESIGN</li>
<li class="landing-pages" style="background-color:#65a8c3;">LANDING PAGES</li>
<li class="web" style="background-color:#59a5c3;">WEB BANNERS</li>
<li class="email" style="background-color:#4aa0c3;">E-MAIL DESIGNS</li>
<li class="print" style="background-color:#3a9bc3;">PRINT ADS</li>
</ul>
</nav>
</div>
```

CSS --->

```
nav.container ul {
    height:60px;
    top:0px;
    margin:0px!important;
    padding:0px!important;
    text-align:center;
}

nav.container {
    position:relative;
    top:-5px;
    width:100%;
    height:60px;
    background-color:#1e94c4;
    z-index:50;
    border-bottom:5px solid #b7e9fc;
}

li.full-web, li.ui, li.landing-pages, li.web, li.email, li.print, li.resume, li.about, li.contact {
    position:relative;
    margin-right:-4px;
    padding-left:13px;
    padding-right:13px;
    padding-top:0px;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    font-family:myriad pro, arial, sans-serif;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-size:1.75em;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:2.15em;
    outline:none;   
    list-style:none;
    display:inline-block;
    transition:750ms;
    -webkit-transition:750ms;
}

li.full-web:hover, li.ui:hover, li.landing-pages:hover, li.web:hover, li.email:hover, li.print:hover, li.resume:hover, li.about:hover, li.contact:hover {
    cursor:pointer;
    background-color:#e9f7ff!important;
    color:#000828;
    border-bottom:10px solid #000828;
    transition:100ms;
    -webkit-transition:100ms;
}

li.full-web:active, li.ui:active, li.landing-pages:active, li.web:active, li.email:active, li.print:active, li.resume:active, li.about:active, li.contact:active {
    top:0px;
    border-bottom:10px solid #86cbe8;
    cursor:pointer;
    outline:none;
    transition:250ms;
    -webkit-transition:250ms;
}
```

Comment: SO MANY `$(this)`ES! Just store it once! Or better yet, don't do it at all! `this.style.backgroundColor = '#e9f7ff';` and so on. Or even better: `this.style.cssText = 'background-color:#e9f7ff; color:#000828; ......';`

Comment: Or, pass along one object, like so: `$(this).css({backgroundColor: '#e9f7ff',color:'#000828',borderBottomColor:'#000828',borderBottomWidth:'10px'});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<nav class="container">
<ul>
<li class="full-web" style="background-color:#3a9bc3;">FULL WEBSITES</li>
<li class="ui" style="background-color:#50a2c3;">UI/DESIGN</li>
<li class="landing-pages" style="background-color:#65a8c3;">LANDING PAGES</li>
<li class="web" style="background-color:#59a5c3;">WEB BANNERS</li>
<li class="email" style="background-color:#4aa0c3;">E-MAIL DESIGNS</li>
<li class="print" style="background-color:#3a9bc3;">PRINT ADS</li>
</ul>
</nav>
</div>

<script>
$('li.full-web, li.ui, li.landing-pages, li.web, li.email, li.print').click(
function(e){
    e.preventDefault; // don't follow the link
    $('.highlight').removeClass('highlight');
    $(this).addClass('highlight')
});
</script>

<style>
.highlight {
    background-color:#e9f7ff!important;
    color:#000828!important;
    border-bottom:10px solid #000828!important;
}
</style>
```